# GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set when running composer update

Tags: git, symfony, vagrant, composer-php

over sudden when I try to do "composer update" it returns the following error. It's a symfony project running on a vagrant machine.

[image]

1. I already tried moving/removing the .git folder and reinitiating it by git init.
2. I tried to destroy the vagrant machine and reprovision it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you manually modified/removed contents in your vendor directory. This is often a bad idea. Best course of action (if you have a lock file) is to `rm -r vendor/` and then do a `composer install`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it came out that after the latest update to OSX Sierra the vagrant machine and its configuration for Symfony stopped working as it supposed to. Initially I noticed that the client machine stopped syncing the shared folder with the host so whatever you can inside of your /var/www/ inside of vagrant will never show up on your host. The vendor folder and its contents included. After I changed the synced_folder vagrant configuration from:

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", type: "rsync",
    rsync__exclude: ["app/", "bin/", "features/", "src/", "tests/", "vendor/", "web/"]
config.vm.synced_folder "app/", "/var/www/app", type: "nfs"
config.vm.synced_folder "bin/", "/var/www/bin", type: "nfs"
config.vm.synced_folder "features/", "/var/www/features", type: "nfs"
config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/var/www/src", type: "nfs"
config.vm.synced_folder "tests/", "/var/www/tests", type: "nfs"
config.vm.synced_folder "vendor/", "/var/www/vendor", type: "nfs"
config.vm.synced_folder "web/", "/var/www/web", type: "nfs"
```

to:

```
    config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", type: 'nfs', mount_options: ['rw', 'vers=3', 'tcp', 'fsc', 'actimeo=2'], rsync__exclude: ["app/", "bin/", "src/", "tests/", "vendor/", "web/"]
    config.vm.synced_folder "app/", "/var/www/app", type: "nfs"
    config.vm.synced_folder "bin/", "/var/www/bin", type: "nfs"
    config.vm.synced_folder "src/", "/var/www/src", type: "nfs"
    config.vm.synced_folder "tests/", "/var/www/tests", type: "nfs"
    config.vm.synced_folder "web/", "/var/www/web", type: "nfs"
```

The sync started working correctly however it seems like there is a permission issue anytime you want to run composer update as a postponing call. The permission error shows up when composer tries to remove any package and install a newer version of it.

This issue only affects vagrant/scotchbox installations with custom configuration for Symfony.